# Can Interface declare only methods?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, interface

I have created the following `interface` and a class that implements it.

```
global interface SampleInterface {
    String logicA();
}

public class SampleClass implements SampleInterface {
    public String logicA();
} 

global class SampleBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    private SampleInterface interface;

    global SampleBatch(SampleInterface interface) {
        this.interface = interface;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // I want to set a variable for SampleClass
        this.interface.aaa = 'aaa';

        this.interface.logicA();
    }

}
```

I want to set a variable for SampleClass

Even though I can add `public string aaa;` in `SampleClass`, within `SampleInterface` I could not could not include `String aaa ;`.

**How can I pass parameters to SampleClass?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a little more flexibility, you may wish to switch to an `abstract class` instead. Doing so will allow you to specify variables as well, and even include some method definitions if you so desire.

```
public abstract class Demo
{
    public Integer foo;
    public abstract String bar();
    void baz()
    {
        system.debug(foo);
    }
}
```

Then your implementations become extensions:

```
public with sharing class Sample extends Demo
{
    public Sample(Integer foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public override String bar()
    {
        return 'LIMIT ' + foo;
    }
}
```